# Apps Script Debugger: "Cannot show for debugging because it has been deleted"

Tags: google-apps-script, editor, v8

The following Google apps script, taken directly from the [documentation for HtmlTemplate.evaluate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template#evaluate):

```
    // A template which evaluates to whatever is bound to 'foo'.
var template = HtmlService.createTemplate('<?= foo ?>');
template.foo = 'Hello World!';
Logger.log(template.evaluate().getContent());  // will log 'Hello World!'
```

produces a popup error message "Cannot show for debugging because it has been deleted" at line 3 in debug mode in the new V8 editor of apps script. It seems to work OK when I just run the script, but it is preventing me from debugging lines further down, and from testing a template with variables in it.

Googling the error message produced no results.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It works okay for me

Comment: @metaman Thank you.  I have confirmed today that it is still a problem.  Every instance I have of template.evaluate().getContent() fails in the debugger, but works with "run" (in other projects too).

Comment: Perhaps someone else can reproduce the problem but I cannot so I'm sorry but I can't help you.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your relevant code? Like the funciton where this code snippet is embedded ?

Comment: @ziganotschka,  thanks for responding.   Here  are my steps for reproducing the problem (which I have done now in both a Google Workplace for Education account and a personal consumer account).  </br> ``` 1.  create a new sheet. 2. open script editor  3. paste the code from google documentation (above) into myFunction 3. set a breakpoint 4. run the debugger  5. at the Logger.log line the debugger will throw the error.  6. stop the debugger  7. run the code and it will work

Comment: Here's a screen recording: [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/19ihYebybQ0AE3H60gsJml9j0UoTAh2m1/view)

Comment: Got you now - this definitely looks like a bug.

Answer (score 3):

In case somebody else experiences the same problem:

**The respective [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/186945182) on Google Issue Tracker could be reproduced by Google and seems to be currently under investigation.**

Please "star" the issue to increase visibility and accelerate the resolution process.